# Three variable inequality with constraints

Tags: inequality

Given $a,b,c$ belongs to $[-1,2]$, $ a+b+c=0$ and $a²+b²+c²\geq 2$. Prove that $abc\geq 0$. Inequality is my weak area so can you guys enlighten me on this one?

Note that by AM-GM, I am getting $abc\leq 0$  !

Comment: Hint: $(-1-a)(-1-b)(-1-c) \le 0$

Comment: $(a+b+c)^{2}=a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+2(ab+ac+bc)=0$. So, $2(ab+ac+bc)\leq -2$ and then $(ab+ac+bc)\leq -1$. Thus, you can obtain result with hint which was given by achille hui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition gives $$(a+b)^2+a^2+b^2\geq2$$ or
$$a^2+ab+b^2\geq1.$$

Let $a\geq b\geq0\geq c$.

Thus, $c=-a-b\geq-1$, which gives $a+b\leq1$.

Hence, $$1\geq(a+b)^2\geq a^2+ab+b^2\geq1,$$ which gives $ab=0$ and $abc\geq0$.

Let $a\geq0\geq b\geq c$.

In this case $abc\geq0$.

The cases $0\geq a\geq b\geq c$ and $a\geq b\geq c\geq 0$ give $a=b=c=0$ and $abc\geq0$ again.

Done!

Answer (score 4):

Since $a+b+c=0$ then $$(a+b+c)^2=0 \Leftrightarrow a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+ac+bc)=0.$$ Using the fact that $a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq 2$ we get that $2(ab+ac+bc) \leq -2$ i.e. $ab+ac+bc \leq -1$   $(*)$.

Now, notice that $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1) \geq 0$, since $a,b,c \in [-1,2]$ and thus $$abc+ab+ac+bc+a+b+c+1 \geq 0.$$ Using $(*)$ and the equality $a+b+c=0$ we get that $abc \geq 0$.